# Question about the Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_2= (Tr(A^*A))^{1/2}$, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint of $A$ with entries $(A^*)_{ij}= \overline{A_{ji}}$

Let $U\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be unitary. Show that $\|UAU^*\|_2 = \|A\|_2$.

I want to say that $\|UAU^*\|_2 = (Tr(UAU^*)^*(UAU^*))= (Tr(UA^*U^*UA^*U^*))=Tr(UA^*AU^*)=(Tr(A^*A))= \|A\|_2$.

But I'm not sure why $Tr(UA^*AU^*)=(Tr(A^*A))$ holds. I feel like I'm not noticing something that's really straightforward here...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace satisfies $\textrm{tr}(AB)=\textrm{tr}(BA)$. In this case $\textrm{tr}(UA^*AU^*)=\textrm{tr}(A^*AU^*U)=\textrm{tr}(A^*A)$.